# Finding the statistical mode of a vector: When having more than single mode — return the last mode

Tags: r, statistical-mode

When calculating the statistical mode of a vector, there is often more than one mode:

```r
c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4) # mode is both 1 and 2
```

In such scenarios, if I want to decide between two (or more) possible values, I use `fmode()` from `{collapse}` package, which offers, through the `ties` argument, 3 possible methods for deciding:

> `ties`
>
> an integer or character string specifying the method to resolve ties between multiple possible > modes i.e. multiple values with the maximum frequency or sum of weights:
>
> | Int. | String | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | first | take the first occurring mode. |
> | 2 | min | take the smallest of the possible modes. |
> | 3 | max | take the largest of the possible modes. |

### Example of `fmode()`

```r
library(collapse)

my_vec <- c(1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5, -6, -6, 2, 2) # 4 modes here: 1, 2, 5, -3

fmode(my_vec, ties = "first")
#> [1] 1
fmode(my_vec, ties = "min")
#> [1] -6
fmode(my_vec, ties = "max")
#> [1] 5
```

---

### My Question

I'm looking for a "last" method — i.e., whenever there's more than one mode, return the "last" mode. But unfortunately, `fmode()` doesn't have a `"last"` method.

So if we return to my example, what I wish is that for the vector:

```r
my_vec <- c(1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5, -6, -6, 2, 2)
```

I want a function that does

```r
custom_mode_func(my_vec, method = "last")
## [1] 2
```

Comment: Would `fmode(rev(my_vec), ties = "first")` satisfy your conditions?

Comment: @DonaldSeinen, thanks! It seems to be working well with vector objects, as well as with grouped `data.frame`, as long as we use `dplyr` methods. However, if we try this solution when grouping with `collapse` functions (i.e., `collapse::fgroup_by()` and `collapse::fsummarise()`) the results are not as expected (i.e., wrong). I guess this is because `collapse` uses its own grouping system, which `fmode()` supports, but `rev()` doesn't.

Comment: Try using dplyr group_by: `data.frame(v = my_vec, g = gl(2, 5)) %>% group_by(g) %>% summarize(last = fmode(rev(v), ties = "first"))`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, yes, this works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only option you have with collapse is sorting the data beforehand e.g.

```r
library(collapse)
my_vec <- c(1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5, -6, -6, 2, 2)
data.frame(v = my_vec, g = gl(2, 5)) %>% 
  roworder(g) %>% 
  tfm(t = data.table::rowid(g)) %>% 
  roworder(g, -t) %>% 
  gby(g) %>% 
  smr(last = fmode(v, ties = "first"))
```

The reason `rev`doesn't work is because collapse grouping doesn't split the data, but only determines to which group a row belongs, and then computes statistics on all groups simultaneously using running algorithms in C++ (e.g. the grouped computation is done by `fmode` itself). So in your code `rev` is actually executed before the grouping and reverses the entire vector. In this case, probably a native data.table implementation calling `fmode.default`directly (to optimize on method dispatch) would be the fastest solution. I can think about adding a `"last"` mode if I find time for that.

Comment: Last mode is implemented from collapse 1.7.1 onwards.